# Suggest edits while over 2000 rep

Tags: feature-request, editing, privileges, suggested-edits

At 2000 rep, users gain the privilege that edits are applied immediately, and loses the ability to suggest edits. However, sometimes I find that I would prefer to suggest edits and leave it up to the author or the community to decide whether the edit is good.

An example: [Can a simple observation (like this) be the answer of the Riemann Hypothesis?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354750/can-a-simple-observation-like-this-be-the-answer-of-the-riemann-hypothesis) is clearly not currently suited for MO. I think I understand the reasoning, and could clean it up, but am not entirely sure, so I would like the author to have the chance to review it before the edit goes live.

Would it be possible to permit users with over 2000 rep to suggest an edit on saving?

Comment: A similar feature request on [meta.se]: [Can I submit an edit for approval after earning 2k reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103270) Some of [the questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/103270) seem related, too.

Comment: For what it's worth, authors can easily rollback your edits, so they're not stuck with it if you make a change they don't like.  It's obviously not the same as what you suggest, but (I think?) the author isn't given the chance to decide on suggested edits either—that's up to reviewers to decide.